# Merge Duplicate rows in SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is my table structure I trying to create a stored procedure that's gets a summary of this information.

```
Part Number  Weight    Type    
----------------------------
234           120       P     
212           45        P
234           110       P
234           100       C
```

Parts that has the same Part Number and type I want to merge the records and get a sum of the weight, output like this.

```
Part Number  Weight    Type    
----------------------------
234           230       P     
212           45        P
234           100       C
```

Answer (score 6):

This is just a simple `GROUP BY` with a `SUM()`:

```
Select  [Part Number], Sum([Weight]) As [Weight], [Type]
From    YourTable
Group By [Part Number], [Type]
```

If you wanted to make it a `STORED PROCEDURE`, the `CREATE` syntax is the following:

```
Create Procedure spGetTotalWeightsByPartAndType --Or whatever you want to name it
As Begin
    Select  [Part Number], Sum([Weight]) As [Weight], [Type]
    From    YourTable
    Group By [Part Number], [Type]
End
```

Comment: Thanks I had a 100 lines of code in my stored procedure to get that to work, it took 30 seconds to run the procedure. Thanks alot.